# Why INTO Clause is expected in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I didn't declare a variable to assign value from query, then why code below throws error for INTO clause?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Disp_of_IPC_Crime_Case(
    startDate DATE,
    endDate   DATE)
IS

BEGIN
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh 
          INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
          ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM= cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM 
          INNER JOIN t_final_report fnr
          ON fnr.FIR_REG_NUM = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
          WHERE MAJOR_HEAD_CD = 8
          AND fr.RECORD_CREATED_ON > (StartDate - INTERVAL '5' YEAR)
          AND NVL(fnr.FR_TYPE_CD,0) =11
          AND NVL(fnr.CHARGSHEET_OR_NOT,'')='N'
    ) Below5COUNTERFEITING;
END;
```

Comment: you get the error because the result of the query needs to be stored somewhere. You can't just run a statement without doing something with the result (and the derived table is totally useless)

Comment: In a PLSQL block you need some variable to fetch the result of a query. The same query, run as a plain SQL, will simply give you the result, but in a block ( anonymous, function, procedure, ...) you need to fetch values into variables and the use the variables

Answer (score 1):

If the aim of the procedure is to provide a report, you can do this by [passing back a ref cursor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets), or if you have Oracle 12.1 or later you can use the new [implicit statement result](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) feature.